# Firebase - Linking Data / Refs on Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Is it possible to link / reference data in our Firebase nodes? For example, let's say I have a node of learning modules and these learning modules are prioritized for each user based on the users score on the module and the particular weight of the module.

Each module has a weight. And the priority of the module for the user is equal to weight*score. Would it be possible to do this somehow?

```
root
  modules
    mod3
       questions:
       answers: 
       weight: 0.8
    mod4
    mod5
    ...

  users
    user1
      mod3
        score: 0.60
        weight: mod3.weight
        priority: weight*score OR (on client, run user1.mod3.score * user1.mod3.weight)
```

The benefit of this is that I can update the weights in one area, and have the module priorities for each user automatically update. If  don't do this, I would have to go through each user and manually update the weights of each module - and this would be a lot more redundant. Is it possible to reference other data like this? If this is not, or if it is but this is not preferable, would be the better answer?

Thank you!

Comment: Firebase is a schema-less database JSON database. Neither Firebase nor JSON has knowledge of your data structure, so it cannot have a structured reference to data in some other part.

That said, it is all just data. You can put in there whatever you like. But you'll have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen! So there is no way to have one value automatically update based on the value of data elsewhere on the node? I would need to write a sever/client side script that runs through the data and manually updates?

Comment: There is no way to run your code on Firebase's servers. You would indeed have to calculate these values with a script that runs separately or simply calculate the values on every update. The alternative would be to *not* store these calculated values and instead add methods like `getPriority` and `getWeight` to your client-side model that calculate the values.